# How to make PGAdmin4 point to my Postgres server instance

Tags: postgresql

My PgAdmin seems to be connected to a Postgres server instance different from what I get connected when I do `psql postgres`. I say that because PgAdmin shows only one database "postgres", but when I do "\l" in psql, I get four (postgres,que_live_dev, template0 &1). I know they are separate instances because if I create a table in PgAdmin under 'postgres' db, the table doesn't appear in psql.

That said, what is PgAdmin connected to, and more importantly, how I re-connect it to the instance including 3 databases?

```
postgres=# \l
                                        List of databases
     Name     |    Owner    | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |      Access privileges      
--------------+-------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------
 postgres     | mainframe02 | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 que_live_dev | mainframe02 | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0    | mainframe02 | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/mainframe02             +
              |             |          |             |             | mainframe02=CTc/mainframe02
 template1    | mainframe02 | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | mainframe02=CTc/mainframe02+
              |             |          |             |             | =c/mainframe02

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres startwaiting for server to start....2021-09-21 17:20:57.127 PDT [5506] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 on x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9), 64-bit
2021-09-21 17:20:57.133 PDT [5506] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2021-09-21 17:20:57.133 PDT [5506] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2021-09-21 17:20:57.134 PDT [5506] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-09-21 17:20:57.145 PDT [5507] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-09-21 15:23:49 PDT
2021-09-21 17:20:57.154 PDT [5506] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
```

Comment: `psql postgres` will connect to server listening on port `5432`. Your `pgAdmin4` connection is listening on another port. Right click on the server in `pgAdmin4` and see what the port is set to in the properties.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!